# I am having a problem to use to object with Fluentvalidation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I can not use the `object` in my code. It says cannot convert from `object` to `FluentValidation.IvalidationContext`.

```
namespace Northwind.Business.Utilities
{
    public static class ValidationTool
    {
        public static void Validate(IValidator validator, object entity)      
        {
            var result = validator.Validate(entity); 
            if (result.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(result.Errors);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it convert from `object` to another type by itself? I think it will be better if you use the generic version of the Validate method.

Comment: I believe you should use `IValidator<T>` with generic type instead of `IValidator`. Cause `IValidator.Validate()` requires a parameter with `IValidationContext` type. For your reference: [`ValidationResult Validate(IValidationContext context)`](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/67042d871fac1f6eb235ffa3785586ea2db05062/src/FluentValidation/IValidator.cs#L56)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get the respective error is mentioned in [Removal of non-generic Validate overload](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/upgrading-to-9.html#removal-of-non-generic-validate-overload) when you are upgrading to version 9.

You can resolve it by providing the `IValidationContext` instance.

```cs
var context = new ValidationContext<object>(model);
var result = validator.Validate(context);
```

Otherwise, you shall consider migrating the validation to `IValidator<T>` with a generic type instead of `IValidator`.